# Error Installing MongoDB driver on XAMPP (OS X/El Capitan)

Tags: macos, php, xampp, mongodb

I'm not new to XAMPP, PHP, or MongoDB, but I'm new to Mac, so getting the [PHP MongoDB driver](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.php.php) set up is causing me more trouble than it probably should.

When I try to run `$ sudo pecl install mongodb` from `/applications/xampp/xamppfiles/bin` I get this error:

```
configure: error: Cannot find OpenSSL's <evp.h>
ERROR: `/private/tmp/pear/install/mongodb/configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config' failed
```

Because I'm so new to Mac, I'm not even sure how to approach this error. I used `which openssl` to see if OpenSSL is installed, and it returned `/usr/bin/openssl`.

Can anyone suggest how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try to link the openssl:

```
$ brew link openssl --force
```

It resolved my issue with openssl.